# Retrieve photos for product with Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent

I'm new to Laravel and I'm working on a Laravel app where 1 to 3 pictures can be uploaded for a product.

Every photo uploaded is a new row in the `product_photos` table with a foreign key to the `products` table like this:

```
id: 39
product_id: 8
filename: photos/PD8Xep1OEjwGFH6TGpHoWc4fmPcPpOjnGMbEe5Qh.jpeg
**************************************************************
id: 40
product_id: 8
filename: photos/dqI4PzrmkWsPY9hQcddN8J0i2HBPPQhBO5b4PzMn.jpeg
```

The relations are the following:

- **Product** Model has a **photos** method that returns **$this->hasMany('App\ProductPhotos')**
- **ProductPhotos** Model has a **product** method that returns **$this->belongsTo('App\Product')**

The below approach yields a

> Property [filename] does not exist on this collection instance

error.

```
$products = Product::all();

foreach ($products as $product) {
    dd($product->photos->filename);
}
```

Is it possible in this case to retrieve the filenames for a product with Eloquent or do I need to use query builder for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to get the `filename` property from a `ProductPhotos` collection, not a `ProductPhotos` model instance.

Try it like this :

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    foreach ($product->photos as $photo) {
        dd($photo->filename);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can do it just with Eoquent no need for the query builder here !!

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach ($products as $product) {
    foreach ($product->photos as $single_photo ) {
        dd($single_photo->filename);
    }
}
```